# PL/SQL block and LOOP exercise

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, block

I have to create a PL/SQL block to insert 10 to 100 multiples of 10 in a table called TEN_MULTIPLES that I have to create... (SCHEMA -> TEN_MULTIPLES(numbervalue)). I will have to insert inside the table only 10,20,30,...,100 but exluding 50 and 90. So far I have done this... is it correct?

```
DECLARE  
  CREATE TABLE ten_multiples
     (numbervalue NUMBER (3));
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 9..101 LOOP
      IF (i = 50 OR i = 90) THEN
      ELSIF (i%10 = 0) THEN
         INSERT INTO ten_multiples
          VALUE (i);
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When I use 10..100 are 10 and 100 included and evaluated as 'i' in the loop?

I need also to find the MAXIMUM number from that table using a cursor, so in this case 100, store it in a variable 'num' declared in the DECLARE part and print it out...

```
DECLAR
   CURSOR my_cursor IS
    SELECT MAX(v_number) FROM ten_multiples;
   num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor;
    FETCH my_cursor INTO (num);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Maximum number is ‘ | num);
  CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
```

Is this right?

I really thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Why is so much PL/SQL coursework consists of exercises in how *not* to use PL/SQL?

```
insert into ten_multiples
with data as ( select level*10 as mult
               from dual
               connect by level <=10)
select * from data
where mult not in (50,90)
/
```

Answer (score 1):

First part:

- You cannot execute the CREATE TABLE statement directly in a PL/SQL
  context. You must use the DBMS_DDL package or dynamic SQL via the
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command, if you must execute within PL/SQL context.
- Yes number literals in the for loop are included.

Second part:

- Use `DECLARE` not `DECLAR`.
- Your `SELECT` member must be a column of the table, not `v_number`.
- Your single quote character is incorrect, use ', not ‘.
- Use double pipe for concatenation, not single.

Finally:

- Actually run these commands through SQL*Plus and listen to the tool.
- Trying is your friend.